# Emtpy debug-window in Eclipse 09-2020 after Mac OS Big Sur Update

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, debugging

After the recent update to Mac OS Big Sur I can’t debug my java projects with Eclipse 09-2020. If I try to inspect the value of any expression, I just get an empty window. I’m working with Oracle JDK 11.

Is there anything I can do, beside waiting for the next eclipse update or using Windows

Comment: Check [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) to see if it has already been reported, if not report it there yourself.

Comment: Same issue on Mac

Comment: Same issue under the same circunstances. Any news about this?

Comment: Same issue. Click on the empty debug window then it will appear.

Comment: I'm also seeing strange screen redraw failures in the Java editor. Scrolling back and forth helps but it's a major annoyance.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568813

Comment: same issue here, but in  DBeaver, which uses eclipse as editor

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue on newly updated Mac Big Sur.
Just **scroll or dragging** your mouse pointer over the empty debug window, the text will show up.

Also, when the debugger jump to another file, it will show only the line that the debugger is pointing at, all other lines stay as same as the last file. Just scroll over it, the file content will show up

Comment: Sometimes it shows after that but most of the times it doesn't

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be fixed in 2020-12 eclipse, which you can download here:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-12/m3/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers

Answer (score 3):

Can click on the marked area. Credit goes to @dangerisgo

[image: Can click on the marked area lie]

Answer (score 1):

One way I have found so far to always get the variable inspector window to show data is to place the mouse pointer over the bottom right corner as close to the corner as possible without going outside of the box.  Usually the cursor would switch to a double arrow to inform you that you can expand the window, but it the cursor stays a single pointer.  Now, click and drag to expand. The data should now show up and can be inspected.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded STS to 4.9.0 e4.18, file name: spring-tool-suite-4-4.9.0.RELEASE-e4.18.0-macosx.cocoa.x86_64
Issue is resolved for me now.
Regards